# Add shadow to toolbar divider

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add white shadow/blur around one of my toolbar divider. Is it possible
Here is the link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=ycysmo51tg). Anybody can help?
Alex

Comment: There are no elements in your fiddle, just a request to collaborate. Please provide example code. [http://stackoverflow.com/tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `width` to `.headerDivider` that way you assign the length of you element.